# Auto Select problem in mat-select with different value and different selected value in edit operation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have mat-select which populates options from the server the object type is an array.
Below is the response body of the array.

```
      /**
   * below array is response that is coming from response
   */
  bizCategoryList$ = [
    { id: 12, category: "business_name", value: "BU1", displayText: "BU1" },
    { id: 13, category: "business_name", value: "BU2", displayText: "BU2" },
    { id: 14, category: "business_name", value: "BU3", displayText: "BU3" },
    { id: 15, category: "business_name", value: "BU4", displayText: "BU4" },
    { id: 16, category: "recession", value: "R1", displayText: "R1" },
    { id: 17, category: "recession", value: "R2", displayText: "R2" },
    { id: 18, category: "recession", value: "R3", displayText: "R3" },    

  ];

<mat-form-field class="flex-25">
<mat-label>Business Name</mat-label>
<mat-select formControlName="businessName">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let bines of bizCategoryList$">
        <mat-option *ngIf="bines.category==='business_name'" [value]="bines.id">
            {{ bines.displayText }}
        </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
</mat-select>
```

On edit, I will auto-select the option with `displayText` but the value of that option should be `id`
Example : `onEdit('BU3')`  the select box should auto-populate with `BU3` and value should be `14(id)`

Comment: could explain further what you wanna do. Where is your onEdit function for e.g.? Best way would be to create a stackblitz.

Comment: @sagat I explained my issue in the code comments section . And here is my link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1yfskk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts